# Trouble passing inputs of User-Defined function to other functions and summing returned values

Tags: python, function, sum

I'm a N00b learning Python.  As part of a small project to create a simple calculator I need a function to take two inputs and determine total costs for a trip.

At the bottom of this code, I have a function called "trip_cost()" that takes two inputs, city and days. City is a string of the city you are going to visit and days is an integer value of days you are staying.

trip_cost() pass the inputs to rental_car_cost, hotel_cost, and plane_ride_cost functions and return a sum of their respective outputs.

I understand that a function can be called from another function as a variable by name but I'm confused as to how I should process the input from trip_cost() into the other functions and return three values to be summed within trip_cost().

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-- Matt

```
def hotel_cost(n):
    nights = n * 140
    return nights

hotel_cost(3)

def plane_ride_cost(c):
    if c =="Charlotte":
        return 183
else:
    if c == "Tampa":
        return 220
    else:
        if c == "Pittsburgh":
            return 222
        else:
            if c == "Los Angeles":
                return 475

plane_ride_cost("Tampa")

def rental_car_cost(d):
    days = 40
    if d >= 7:
    return d * days - 50
elif d >= 3:
    return d * days - 20
else:
    return d * days

rental_car_cost(3)

def trip_cost(c,d):
    return sum (hotel_cost) + sum(rental_car_cost) + sum (plane_ride_cost)

trip_cost("Tampa",3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a "better" version of yours, sice you are learning python, I've put a lot of things here:

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):  # First, in this case, I used a dictionary
    return {                # to get a value of a city
        'Charlotte': 183,
        'Tampa': 220,
        'Pittsburgh': 222,
        'Los Angeles': 475
    }[city]

def hotel_cost(nights):     # You can always use expressions in
    return nights * 140     # the return statement

def rental_car_cost(days):  # If it is possible, use long variable
    cost = 40               # names, not just one letters -> readability counts
    if days >= 7:
        return days * cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        return days * cost - 20
    else:
        return days * cost

def trip_cost(city, days):  # You can just add the values together, that is SUM
    return hotel_cost(days) + rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city)
```

Demo:

```
print trip_cost('Tampa', 3) # Call the 'main' function, with variables
```

And this will return:

```
# 740
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for the advice.  I does look better to use a Dictionary in the function. The way I am doing it seems more complicated.

Comment: @matt That's OK, I've done dirtier things, when I started coding.. What matters, is that never stop learning and practicing! If you think my answer was useful, please vote up, an accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `sum()` here because the following would work and require little overhead:

```
def trip_cost(c, d):
    return hotel_cost(d) + rental_car_cost(d) + plane_ride_cost(c)
```

However, you *could* use`sum()`with something like the following, which creates a tuple of the results of calling each cost function, and then pass that object to`sum()`to be totaled.

```
def trip_cost(c, d):
    return sum((hotel_cost(d), rental_car_cost(d), plane_ride_cost(c)))
```

Another alternative would be to use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions), but it would require each of the functions to accept the same input arguments even if they didn't use both of them. ***If*** they were rewritten to be that way, it would allow you to do something along these lines:

```
def trip_cost(c, d):
    cost_functions = (hotel_cost, rental_car_cost, plane_ride_cost)
    return sum(cf(c, d) for cf in cost_functions)
```

With this, the calls to each cost function would occur at the same time`sum()`was executing. Something like that might be useful if you wanted the tuple of functions to vary, in which case you could pass them to the`trip_cost()`function as an additional argument instead of hardcoding them. However based on your current code and apparent needs, the first way would probably be the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks that did it (i.e., sum() with the function reference).  I appreciate the advice...seems like I was stuck on a simple syntax error.

Comment: @martineau except that that's a tuple, not a genexp.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city=='Charlotte':
        return 183
    elif city=='Tampa':
        return 220
    elif city=='Pittsburgh':
        return 222
    elif city=='Los Angeles':
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    day = 40
    cost = days*day
    if days >= 7:
        cost = cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost = cost - 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city,days):
    city = plane_ride_cost(city)
    return city+rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)
```